# u-boot imx6 how to set console to UART4

Tags: u-boot, imx6

I am trying to set the u-boot console on an imx6 board to UART4. And it is not working. UART1 stops working, but I never get output.

In my board .h file:

```
    #define CONFIG_MXC_UART
#define CONFIG_MXC_UART_BASE        UART4_BASE
#define CONSOLE_DEV "ttymxc3"           /* added to changee console to UART4 */
```

in my board .c file:

```
static struct mxc_serial_platdata mxc_serial_plat = {
.reg = (struct mxc_uart *)UART4_BASE,
.use_dte = false,
};

U_BOOT_DEVICE(mxc_serial) = {
    .name = "serial_mxc",
    .platdata = &mxc_serial_plat,
};
```

I have enabled the pins via the IOMUX. What am I missing? Why can't I get any output?

Dennis

Comment: Turned out TX and RX were swapped on the schematic, now I have TX data, but no RX data. An it looks like no other boards in u-boot use the same UART4 pin, PAD_CSI0_DAT12__UART4_RX_DATA.